# Error - evaluation version expired when acessing my site application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I've created a new sharepoint application so I could use the my site feature. For that i've followed this tutorial:

http://odole.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/how-to-configure-shared-service-provider-and-mysite/

which made me create an application for the sharedservices provider (http://moss2k7:50000/)and another for the my site (http://moss2k7:1/).

But when I try to access the my site application I get the sharepoint error:

> The evaluation version of Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 for
>   this server has expired

although my license is valid and I can do other stuff with sharepoint.

I've search for a solution and find out these ones:

- Add read permissions to WSS_WPG and Full permissions for WSS_ADMIN_WPG - which they already had;
- Add "%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Bin;%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office Servers\12.0\Bin;" to the MIDDLE of the PATH environment variable

But none of those worked.

Any Additional solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're running MOSS and not WSS (if you're using WSS, you'll need to upgrade to get the my site feature). However I remember back when the first service pack came out, there was a little surprise where it sometimes deleted your key (happened to us and we couldn't figure out why our search stopped working for about three days). Double check in Central Administration > Operations > Convert License Type. If it says evaluation, just reenter your product key and it should work again.